# strings in println(); method

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Strings to be printed");
```

In the above line of code, the strings are coated with double inverted commas
and when we want to print the non-string values or variables, we separate by commas.

Does the compiler ask for the commas? or is it required by the `println();` to determine the strings separately?

Comment: Commas show it is string to compiler or else compiler will waste time in compiling it as int or others.

Comment: System.out.println() is override function 
check [link] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why is inverted commas required by println();?

It is not so much required by `println` as *required by the Java language*.

The `println` method takes a String argument, and the way to write a String literal in Java is you put double-quote characters around it.

If you didn't put the double-quotes around 'String to be printed' then the Java Language Specification says that you have a sequence of 4 identifiers: `String` `to` `be` `printed`.  That is not a valid Java expression ... and you will get a compilation error.

---

Why is it that way?  Well, it is also consistent with the vast majority of other programming languages ... including Java's direct antecedents ... and that is as good an explanation as you are likely to get.

I suppose you could also be asking why they *need to* have rules like this: why couldn't the compiler just figure out what the programmer means.  And the answer to that is that it is beyond the state of the art ... and probably beyond the realms of possibility.  (How does a compiler  figure out what the programmer means, when a lot of the time the programmer doesn't know himself!?)

Comment: a computer, literally, is the dumbest thing ever. Even a stone thrown upwards falls down with the pinnacle of perfection and precision?.Well, why? because gravity guides the stone unlike compiler, guided by the most error-prone brain, human.

Comment: @ArpanAdhikari - I'm not sure if that is profound ... or drivel :-).  Anyway, my point is that expecting a compiler to (somehow) know what a programmer is thinking is ... ludicrous.  A program needs to have a single, definite and discernible meaning, and the only practical way to achieve that is through a specified syntax that does not change at the whim of the programmer.

Comment: Be sure, sir, I was not being profound, my opinion was, If we had been a little more creative, your super-mind-reading compiler would be possible!:-D  .., your answer took me to the next level, thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

### [Java: Creating Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

> The most direct way to create a string is to write:
>
> ```
> String greeting = "Hello world!";
> ```
>
> In this case, `"Hello world!"` is a string literal—a series of
>   characters in your ***code that is enclosed in double quotes***.
>   Whenever it encounters a string literal in your code, the compiler
>   creates a String object with its value—in this case, `Hello world!`.

So it's not the requirement of `println()` but it is a way to create a string literal in Java.

Comment: Good answer but the first part should be in blockquotes to make it clear it comes from the link.

Answer (score 0):

`"Strings to be printed"`

This is called a String Literal. The compiler understands it as a string. If you want to add a " in the middle of it you use a \ before it to escape the character.

`"Strings \"to\" be printed"`